# jquery - swfobject loading mp3 onclick

Tags: jquery, flash, swfobject

So I'm using swfobject and I wrote a simple audio player in Flash, however I want to tell the player what mp3's to play when I click a link.
So I figured I would do something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#run').click(function() {
        so.addVariable("audioURL", "track05.mp3");
   });
});
```

and I load the player like so...

```
    <div id="flashcontent"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        var so = new SWFObject("musicplayer.swf", "sotester", "550px", "400px", "8", "#fff");
        so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
        so.write("flashcontent");
        // ]]>
    </script>


<a href="#" id="run">run</a>
```

So this type of thing does not work, is it something I'm doing wrong in flash or jquery? any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Are first loading the player then trying to change the `audioURL` variable?

Comment: Yes it is fully loaded before I click the link.

Answer (score 0):

Flash, once embedded, cannot intercept new flashvar properties.

If you are looking to change the audio file via a JavaScript click, you'll want to look into [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are swf media players with an API that allows one to change media on the fly via javascript, but not through changing the flashvar.